# Why is $\infty^0$ an indeterminate form?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, indeterminate-forms

I can't seem to find a situation where $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=0$, but $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)^{g(x)}\neq 1$.  This makes me think that, even though this form ($\infty^0$) is often stated as an indeterminate form, it is not actually indeterminate (since the limit is always 1).

Moreover, I cant find a question asking this on stackexchange, and the calculus book I use neglects to provide an explanation for why it is considered indeterminate.

I have tried to prove that the limit is always 1, but it has been a few years since my real analysis days, and I am getting stuck in the proof.  I'll continue to look for a proof, but in the mean time, I figured I would ask the question, and see if anyone can provide an example I've missed.

Comment: Don't take it wrong, but it is a little suicidal to contradict what is written in every textbook.

Comment: While I agree with that, the fact that the textbook did not provide an explanation for why it was an indeterminate made me skeptical.  Any problem ended up being 1 in the exercises.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't trying hard enough. \begin{align}&\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{1/\ln x}=\lim_{x\to\infty} e=e\\ &\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{(\ln x)^{-1/2}}=\infty\end{align}

Comment: Please explain this undue downvote.

Comment: great!  Thank you for the response.  I suppose I could have tried more examples before asking the question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Did someone downvote my answer?

Comment: @Gae.S.: yep, three upvotes before.

Answer (score 2):

Another example $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}(e^x)^{1/x}=e$$
Before finding the limit $f(x)=(e^x)^{1/x}$ gives $f(\infty)= \infty^0$ which is only a `warning sign' that our calculational intuition may fail us when we deal with very small and very big numbers. But evaluation of $f(x)$ for large values of $x$ e.g.
10,100,1000, ... $f(x)$ may go down to a good number which would be 2.71.... But normally we do not do numerics, so we should follow and appropriate method for this warning sign, the method is $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)^{g(x)}=\exp[\lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x) \log f(x)]$